# Java 8 – DateTimeFormatter: formatting Oracle dates

Tags: java, oracle, date, java-8, datetimeformatter

I have this function:

```
private static boolean isDate(String rowData, String pattern) {

    try {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, Locale.getDefault());
        LocalDate.parse(rowData, formatter).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;

    }

}
```

and

```
private static final String ORACLE_DATE_FORMAT1 = "MMM d, yyyy";
private static final String ORACLE_DATE_FORMAT2 = "dd MMM yyyy";

System.out.println("<--------------------------->");
System.out.println("value -> " + value);
System.out.println("isDate -> " + (isDate(value, ORACLE_DATE_FORMAT1) || isDate(value, ORACLE_DATE_FORMAT2)));
System.out.println("<--------------------------->");
```

but I get this result:

```
value -> 1 Aug 2020
isDate -> false
<--------------------------->
<--------------------------->
value -> 31 Jul 2099
isDate -> true
```

Comment: Try `01 Aug 2020`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works if you change `ORACLE_DATE_FORMAT2` to `d MMM yyyy`. As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns), when the date is specified as `dd`, it expects a 2-character representation of the day of the month (e.g. 01 Aug 2020).

Note that this change will pick up both `1 Aug 2020` and `01 Aug 2020` successfully.

```
<--------------------------->
value -> 01 Aug 2020
isDate -> true
<--------------------------->
```

```
<--------------------------->
value -> 1 Aug 2020
isDate -> true
<--------------------------->
```